# IoT - Sensor Fault Detection and Isolation Techniques using Fuzzy-Model

Tags: fuzzy

Im working on a project which use fuzzy-model based fault detection and isolation technique to detect and diagnose possible fault occurrence on multiple types of sensor. I got stuck with the scheme of fuzzy-model based fault detection and isolation system itself. Ive been searching all over the Internet but i got no clue where i should start to learn about it.
Does anyone here can recommend me where should i start to learn about FDI technique?
Books recommendation would be great.